# Get index of grouped data

Tags: pandas, group-by

So simple, so hard to find an answer.

How do you get the index of a grouped DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ["this", "that", "this", "this", "that", "this"], 
                   'b': [1,2,3,4,5,6]})
groups = df.groupby(['a'])
i = iter(groups)
g = next(i)
print(g)

#OUTPUT#################
('that',       a  b  
1  that  2 
4  that  5)
```

How do I get the index values of 1 and 4 like `[1,4]`

Note, this is just an example, I have to use groupby. Counting or selecting from the parent dataframe is not a solution.

Comment: `df.index.groupby(df['a'])`?

Comment: @QuangHoang good thought, but I need the other values in the group.  Of course I could do it via mask that way... let me check

Comment: @QuangHoang, yep that works, thanks.